# Query execution failed for dataset. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, dataset, reporting, reporting-services-2016

I've developed few reports. More of them are working fine in develop environment. after successfull testing they were published on web. But one of them if I press "View Report"  following error occurs.

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'xxx'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand) 
For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors
```

Answer (score 0):

My dataset result doesnt get. I changed my sp result and it solved it. Maybe this help someone.
Thank you